# Where is the error happening in this build

Tags: c, freebsd

I am not a C programmer so I am aware that I am in over my head.

How do I locate where this error is occurring and determine what it is?  This appears to me to be the relevant output from the make command.

```
gmake --debug=jv
. . . 
Putting child 0x8006e6600 (/home/byrnejb_hll/Projects/AB4-1/aubit4glsrc/lib/libaubit4gl-1.5_3.so) PID 77727 on the chain.
Live child 0x8006e6600 (/home/byrnejb_hll/Projects/AB4-1/aubit4glsrc/lib/libaubit4gl-1.5_3.so) PID 77727 
/usr/local/bin/ld: keys.o:/home/byrnejb_hll/Projects/AB4-1/aubit4glsrc/incl/a4gl_libaubit4gl.h:1026: multiple definition of `abort_pressed'; fglwrap.o:(.bss+0xe0): first defined here
/usr/local/bin/ld: report.o: in function `A4GL_internal_open_report_file':
/usr/home/byrnejb_hll/Projects/AB4-1/aubit4glsrc/lib/libaubit4gl/report.c:764: warning: warning: tmpnam() possibly used unsafely; consider using mkstemp()
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Reaping losing child 0x8006e6600 PID 77727 
gmake[2]: *** [Makefile:211: /home/byrnejb_hll/Projects/AB4-1/aubit4glsrc/lib/libaubit4gl-1.5_3.so] Error 1
Removing child 0x8006e6600 PID 77727 from chain.
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/home/byrnejb_hll/Projects/AB4-1/aubit4glsrc/lib/libaubit4gl'
Reaping losing child 0x8006d2960 PID 77684 
gmake[1]: *** [Makefile:276: libaubit4gl-1.5_3.so] Error 2
Removing child 0x8006d2960 PID 77684 from chain.
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/home/byrnejb_hll/Projects/AB4-1/aubit4glsrc/lib'
Reaping losing child 0x8006e4200 PID 77600 
gmake: *** [Makefile:285: corecompile] Error 2
Removing child 0x8006e4200 PID 77600 from chain.
```

The code in ./lib/libaubit4gl.h is:

```
1024 #ifdef OBJECTMODULE$
1025   char opts[100][80];^I^I/*menu options */$
1026   int abort_pressed;$
1027   int relxedit = 0, relyedit = 0;$
1028   int aborted;$
1029   long time_offset = 0;$
1030   int week_no = -1;$
1031   struct s_form_attr std_dbscr;$
1032 #else$
1033   extern char opts[10][80];^I/*menu options */$
1034   extern int abort_pressed;$
1035   extern int relxedit, relyedit;$
1036   extern int aborted;$
1037   extern long time_offset;$
1038   extern int week_no;$
1039   dll_import struct s_form_attr std_dbscr;$
1040 #endif$
```

This is the only place where `abort_pressed` is mentioned.

The code in fglwrap.c, again the only place where `abort_pressed` is used

```
1450 void$
1451 A4GL_def_quit (void)$
1452 {$
1453 #ifdef DEBUG$
1454   A4GL_debug ("FIXME: DEFER QUIT NOT IMPLEMENTED - Setting quit mode");$
1455 #endif$
1456 }$
1457 $
1458 int abort_pressed=0;$
1459 $
1460 /**$
1461  *$
1462  * @todo Describe function$
1463  */$
1464 void$
1465 A4GL_set_abort (int a)$
1466 {$
1467 #ifdef DEBUG$
1468   A4GL_debug ("set_abort called with %d", a);$
1469 #endif$
1470   abort_pressed = a;$
1471 }$
1472 $
```

What is the correct way of handling this?  I am trying to get a program that used to work to work again, but I am not the author.

Comment: The only actual error is the "multiple definition of 'abort_pressed'". What is `abort_pressed`? Do you know the difference between a *declaration* and a *definition*? Perhaps you define `abort_pressed` in a header file when you really should be declaring it?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/ld: keys.o:/home/byrnejb_hll/Projects/AB4-1/aubit4glsrc/incl/a4gl_libaubit4gl.h:1026: multiple definition of 'abort_pressed'; fglwrap.o:(.bss+0xe0): first defined here` means that `abort_pressed` is defined on line 1026 of `a4gl_libaubit4gl.h` and also somewhere in `fdlwrap.o` (it seems like it wasn't compiled with debug symbols so it doesn't give the line number of the source code).

Comment: Please don't add code snippets with line-numbers or editor formatting characters.

Comment: Now for your problem: Look for source file where `OBJECTMODULE` is defined. I'll bet it's defined in another file than `fglwrap.c`. That would mean that you indeed have multiple definitions of `abort_pressed`. Once in `fglwrap.c` and then once in the other file where `OBJECTMODULE` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Yea so it looks like there's multiple definitions of "abort_pressed", which is sourced to a ".h" file (header file). You are not supposed to DEFINE variables in your .h files, just DECLARE them. You CAN get away with this if you only include a .h file ONCE, but if you include it twice you will get this error.

Look into the difference between declaring and definitions, and move your definition out of your .h file. This is best practice for coding in C, even if you only need to include your .h file in one place

As for the mechanics of what's going on, your compiler copies and pastes all of your .h files into wherever you have included them ie. "#include "header.h" will paste all of the code of header.h wherever it's written. You're allowed to DECLARE things multiple times, ie. declaring a function "math" -

```
void math(uint8_t val);
```

Things like that can be written into your code as many times as you want, so when they are pasted multiple times, your compiler doesn't get confused. However, when you DEFINE things, ie. defining a variable "globalFlags"

```
uint32_t globalFlags;
```

This confuses the compiler, because it's creating a value "globalFlags" in memory, that can be accessed by the keyword, "globalFlags". If you try to create a 2nd version, the compiler will be confused, as it will not know which of the two memory addresses to access, since "globalFlags" applies to both. So it throws an error, and tells you to fix that

Comment: More exactly, the linker detected the case at hand when linking all modules together. It is not confused, it found an error and happily reported it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue with legacy code.  Either headers or source files define a variable that they instead should only declare.

This comes from the traditional UNIX linking model; C originally didn't have pure references nor `extern` keyword, much like other languages of the time.

Also, to put it in context, early C had no prototypes, struct member names were not namespaced (this is why struct members in old interfaces like BSD sockets are prefixed), and basically it couldn't tell things apart from each other but by their names, it was really primitive back then.

So instead of references, variables would be placed in a (special) common section in object files, and any duplicates would be merged by the linker by looking at it; following the approach used by FORTRAN if I'm not mistaken.

The linker still does it's part, it processes object files and tries to resolve the symbols in the common section to something else, and whatever is left of it at the end is placed in the BSS (uninitialised/zero data).

The compiler would put any tentative declaration (i.e. without initialiser value) in this common section.

GCC followed this approach for C by default, until GCC 10, when it changed to the same approach used for C++, i.e. to put these directly in the BSS; a fair thing since:

- we had a better way to deal with this for over 30 years
- generated machine code isn't always optimal
- the unix model contradicts the C standard a bit
- no way to tell if the duplicated definitions are intentional or accidental (so a bad practice)

However, GCC can still compile legacy code unmodified, if you can't or won't modify it, it's just a switch away: `-fcommon`.

Comment: I tried this, keeping in mind that I am learning as I go:  `gmake clean; ./configure --with-build-cflags=-fcommon ;  gmake`.
The result was identical to that obtained previously:`/usr/local/bin/ld: keys.o:/home/byrnejb_hll/Projects/AB4-1/aubit4glsrc/incl/a4gl_libaubit4gl.h:1026: multiple definition of 'abort_pressed'; fglwrap.o:(.bss+0xe0): first defined here`.  Have I misunderstood how the complier flag is to be passed to gcc?

Comment: Just set the CFLAGS variable when calling the configure script; e.g.: `CFLAGS="-O2 -march=native -fcommon" ./configure`